# Manage different stocks for different stores/store views in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, inventory, stores, scope

My site has different stores(city as it is called). I want to manage the stocks for these stores.
i.e.
"Assign/manage different product quantity to each store for the same product."
or in other word (if i am interpreting correctly)
"Change magento inventory settings to store view scope instead of global(default)."

I know that we have a few paid modules available online which incorporate warehouses to solve this issue. But their prices are huge.

Could you please give me some logic to work this out.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`Demac_MultiLocationInventory`](https://github.com/DemacMedia/Magento-Multi-Location-Inventory) can help you - they just released this extension on GitHub. It should do exactly what you try to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I intalled the extension and created a location. But I am getting this error when I click on "manage products" - 'Fatal error: Call to undefined method Demac_MultiLocationInventory_Model_CatalogInventory_Resource_Stock::loadByWebsiteId() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/public_html/app/code/community/Smile/Warehouse/Model/Stock.php on line 81'

Comment: also how do I create inventory? Thnks!

Comment: If you have any problems with the extension, you should open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/DemacMedia/Magento-Multi-Location-Inventory/issues).

Comment: A little late, but for anyone looking at this in the future...  There was a bug causing the error @subz was experiencing. It has since been fixed and documentation explaining how to get started has been added.